# How do I restore Unity configuration (and other problems) after hard reboot?

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher, themes, desktop-background

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. It locked up on me, and I did a hard reboot. (I had to reboot by physically holding down the power button.) What happens now, is my wallpaper, my icons in the Launcher, my theme -- it is all gone.

I am also missing stuff in my Launcher that was there, and there are icons there that I didn't have there before (or that I had removed when I started customizing). I am back to the default Unity theme.

But it's more than just a missing theme. As I say, the items I had in my Launcher are missing too. Some of these are a real problem because I installed them through the Software Center, and so I do not know the Terminal command for them. And customizations like auto-hiding the launcher are gone, too. International keyboards that I had installed are gone.

And there is one more piece of weirdness. In the login screen, I have my wallpaper, custom icons, etc. (but not the keyboards). Once I log in, then it there are the problems that I have described.

I am open for any suggestions on how to resolve this.

Here are the contents of some the relevant logs:

```
$ ls -ld ~/.xsession-errors{,.old} ~/.config
drwx------ 1 grace grace 1064 Dec 28 23:10 /home/grace/.config
-rw------- 1 grace grace  835 Feb  2 15:35 /home/grace/.xsession-errors
-rw------- 1 grace grace  638 Feb  2  2017 /home/grace/.xsession-errors.old

$ more .xsession-errors.old
Script for ibus started at run_im.
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd respawning too fast, stopped

$ ls -lR ~/.config/unity
/home/grace/.config/unity:
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 grace grace 0 Jan 13  2015 first_run.stamp
```

The file `.xsession-errors` is empty.

It was suggested to me by another user to include links to more of my log files (in `/var/log`), in case they are relevant. Here they are:

- [Xorg.0.log](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23913563/)
- [Xorg.0.log.old](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23913584/)
- [Xorg.1.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23913594/)
- [Xorg.1.log.old](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23913601/)
- [syslog](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23913617/)
- [dmesg](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23913630/)
- [kern.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23913668/)

Comment: Something else I noticed. Ubuntu now ignores any setting I try to make with `unity-tweak-tool`. I mean _completely_ ignores.  I am also unble to change theme or any other aspect of appearance using System Settings.

Comment: Another thing: When I try to auto-hide the Launcher  using System Settings, it will not let me slide the swtich from "on" to "off". If I try to enable workspaces, the little checkmark next to "Enable workspaces" disappears as soon as I let go of the mouse. Same applies to "Add show desktop icon to deskbar".

Comment: In a new administrator account I created, I was able to use System Settings to change wallpaper, theme, etc.

Comment: By request, here is the [output of gsettings list-schemes](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23918060/)

Comment: Did @GunnarHjalmarsson find the root cause?  If yes, I'll delete my answer and upvote his.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that the `~/.config/dconf/user` file was corrupted. You can test that theory by renaming the file to e.g. `user.old`, **log out and then log in again**, and see if that measure affects the possibilities to change the settings.

If that fails, reboot before trying anything else...

Comment: I did what you said an rebooted. Nothing changed; I still couldn't use System Settings or Unity Tweak Tool. Then I did software updates and shut down the computer (powered off). Later I powered up again. I tried using System Settings & Unity Tweak Tool again, and voila! I was able to change theme, auto-hide Launcher, install keyboards, etc.  My old settings are lost, I guess, but I am slowly putting this back together. Went to Software Center to double-check what I had installed so I can get the icons back in the Launcher.

Comment: @gracious1: If you still have the old version of the settings file (named `user.old`) your old setttings may not be lost, after all. May be worth a try, maybe.

Answer (score 4):

As you said in chat that this does not happen in the guest account, use the following steps to circumvent the issue: (this is a **workaround**, not a solution)

- create a new user (E.g. `user2` for original user `user`)
- with the same groups as the other user.  (go to a terminal and execute `groups` to verify logged on to each user and that they have the same output)

Now:

1. open the file manager
2. browse to the `/home/user` directory
3. **copy** (not move!) *all the files and directories* from Downloads to `/home/user2/Downloads`
4. check you did a good job.
5. Now delete `/home/user/Downloads`
6. Go back to step 3 and repeat for Documents, Videos, ...
7. In a terminal type the following command: `deluser user --remove-home`

## Done!

**Why?** As you have <strike>seriously messed up</strike> some problems with the current's user profile, some setting somewhere in one of the `.config` files or directory permissions is causing a problem.  As we can't solve this problem in a reasonable amount of time, it's best to just leave that profile behind and starting afresh!

Comment: Although I didn't need this workaround this time, this a great resource to refer to another time should it ever be necessary to take these steps!