# Login only as guest, after have modified ~/.profile file

Tags: login, guest-session, accounts

Yesterday I have modified the file `.profile`, adding a new PATH at the end of it. After this change I can only login as guest user. Could these two things be connected? How could I solve this problem?

This is my `.profile` file content:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
     include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
 set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ubuntu stuck in a login loop after editing profile file](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148571/ubuntu-stuck-in-a-login-loop-after-editing-profile-file)

Comment: When logged in as guest, enter `su <user>` in terminal, where `<user>` is your username. This will ask for your password, but not do a full login and thus not source `.profile.` Then `cd`to your home directory and edit `.profile` again (revertyour changes...)

Comment: @ridgy I have created a new account, than I have switched user, and finally I have modified `.profile`. Unfortunately this don't have solved the problem.

Comment: @ridgy: You are not permitted to use `su` as guest.

Comment: Can you show us the whole `~/.profile` file for the first user. (Edit your question with the additional info.)

Comment: @Gunnar Yesterday I have also modified `bashrc`

Comment: Then how about reverting that `~/.bashrc` change. (`~/.profile` looks good AFAICT, assuming that there is a `#` character before the comment.)

Comment: @Gunnar I have reverted  both`~/.bashrc` `~/.profile` ,but I can't directly access to my account yet.

Comment: So you messed up your $HOME some other way, then. There is always 'the emergency exit' as explained in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/879619).